# Extract final coef in stepwise regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am doing a stepwise regression: `step(lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5))`.
How can i extract the final values of the coeff with the name of these coef ?(I have to do this through a loop as I have 300 regressions).
When I use `$coefficients`, i get all the regressions and not only the final one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `coef` function to extract the coefficients together with the term names of the last model.

```
fit <- step(lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5))

coef(fit)
```